# "Он стал настаивать, чтобы она ему открылась" - Целевое или определительное ПП?

Tags: cинтаксис

*Он стал настаивать, **чтобы она ему открылась**.*

Как надо правильно спрашивать: *настаивал на чем*? или *настаивал с какой целью*?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это придаточное изъяснительное. Настаивать на чём? Здесь ***чтобы*** не целевой союз.

Comment: Tagirix, скажите пожалуйста, и в след. примере союз "чтобы" не целевой? это опять изъяснительное предложение? "Она была слишком гордой, чтобы шпионить за мужем."
(гордой для чего?)

Comment: Да. Семантика цели здесь тоже не прослеживается.